# Magnetisation and the field energy

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, material-science, magnetic-moment

"The phase with higher magnetisation has lower energy in a field; this energy difference is the driving force of the transformation."

I want to fully understand this sentence (there might be a language barrier for me regarding type of energies)

If I picture an example with single magnetic domain within the material, the internal energy is maximal. (That is why the material wants more domains to minimalize its energy depending on conditions) The magnetisation should be also maximal. Why the "The phase with higher magnetisation has lower energy in a field"?

Comment: Is there any more context regarding where the sentence came from that you can share.  This might indicate some important assumptions or constraints.  I hope this helps.

Comment: It is about magnetically induced phase transformation, shape memory alloys.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272249390_Magnetic_Shape_Memory_Effect_and_Highly_Mobile_Twin_Boundaries sedond page